# Multiple Models in a single django ModelForm error IntegrityError

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have one formulaic with mutiples models and to mark the mistake to the moment to guard the information

I leave them the mistake that marks me when I try to guard the information

```
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/cliente/
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
app_empresa.cliente_id may not be NULL
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 450
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home/servicio/www/frente',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/merengue-0.9.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_su-0.4.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/recaptcha_client-1.0.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_inplaceedit-0.82-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_classy_tags-0.3.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_compressor-1.1.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_autoreports-0.8.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_form_admin-0.4.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_configfield-0.2.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/searchform-0.1.3dev-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sorl_thumbnail-11.12-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_transmeta-0.6.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_inlinetrans-0.6.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/transhette-0.5.10-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cmsutils-0.6.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_stdfile-0.5-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_genericforeignkey-0.60.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_oot-0.8.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_announcements-0.1.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_notification-0.1.5-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_threadedcomments-0.5.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_ajax_selects-1.1.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_oembed-0.1.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_mptt-0.4.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_debug_toolbar-0.8.5-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/template_utils-0.4p2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/johnny_cache-1.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_pagination-1.0.7-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_tagging-0.3.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cssutils-1.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_extensions-0.5-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/South-0.7.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_twitter-0.8.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/feedparser-5.1.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/encutils-0.9-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup-3.2.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_appconf-0.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_jsonfield-0.8.11-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/polib-1.0.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2-1.5.211-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six-1.5.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol'
```

Later I leave them my model

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellido_Materno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellido_Paterno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    puesto = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    telefono = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, unique=True, validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^\d{10}$', message='Debe de se de  10 digitos', code='Invalid number')])
    mail = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.nombre

class Empresa(models.Model):
    nombreEmpresa = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    calle = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    numero_Exterior = models.IntegerField()
    numero_Interior = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Colonia = models.ForeignKey(Colonia)
    delegacion = models.ForeignKey(Delegacion)
    rutas = models.ManyToManyField(Ruta)
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria)
    subcategoria1 = models.ForeignKey(Subcategoria1)
    subcategoria2 = models.ForeignKey(Subcategoria2)
    subcategoria3 = models.ForeignKey(Subcategoria3)
    position = GeopositionField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

my views.py

```
def register_cliente(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form_a = CreateCliente(request.POST, prefix="cli")
        form_b = CreateEmpresa(request.POST, prefix="emp")
        if form_a and form_b.is_valid():
            cliente = form_a.save(commit = False)
            cliente.empresa = form_b.save()
            return HttpResponse('registro Realisado')
        else:
            form_a = CreateCliente(prefix="cli")
            form_b = CreateEmpresa(prefix="emp")
        context = {}
        context.update(csrf(request))
        context['form_a'] = form_a
        context['form_b'] = form_b
        #Pass the context to a template
        return render_to_response('registercliente.html', context)
    else:
        form_a = CreateCliente(prefix="cli")
        form_b = CreateEmpresa(prefix="emp")
        return render(request, 'registercliente.html', {'form_a': form_a,'form_b': form_b})
```

my forms.py

```
class CreateCliente(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Cliente
        fields = ('nombre','apellido_Paterno','apellido_Materno','puesto','telefono','mail')

class CreateEmpresa(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Empresa
        fields = ('nombreEmpresa','calle','numero_Exterior','numero_Interior','Colonia','delegacion')
```

my html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form action="." method="POST"> 
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form_a.as_p }}
    {{ form_b.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Guardar">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you are saving forms, as below

```
    if form_a and form_b.is_valid():

        cliente = form_a.save()
        empresa = form_b.save(commit=False)
        empresa.cliente = cliente
        empresa.save()
        return HttpResponse('registro Realisado')
```

`empresa.cliente` should not be null, so when you are doing `form_b.save()` that field is null and hence you are getting the error.